# Far как компилятор для C++

Tags: компилятор, visual-studio

Есть Visual studio 9.0. Есть Far. Задача - заставить Far компилировать `*.cpp`, `*.c` файлы. Как это делается?

Answer (score 1):

С FAR не работал, поэтому конкретные настройки вам не скажу. Но вот в [ЭТОЙ СТАТЬЕ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235639.aspx) Вы можете почитать про использование интерфейса командной строки для компиляции программ на С++...

Могу предположить, что определив для FAR соответствующие переменные окружения (смотрите команду set в Visual Studio command prompt) и указав для выполнения компиляции команду вызова компилятора Microsoft (cl ...) можно добиться желаемого эффекта.